# How to keep relative path in Django templates?

Tags: python, html, css, django

I have imported a front-end project including completed .css, .js, .html files into Django templates. They can work when run .html directly. But if run them in Django server, all links with relative path should be modified as Django style such as

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'style.css' %}" />`

instead of 
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />`.

Is there any method to keep the orginal relative path in .html file and also can run in Django?

===========================================================================
I've solve my problem, the solutions are add their path into urls.py under primary program.

```
if settings.DEBUG:
urlpatterns += [
    url(r'^(?P<path>css.*)$', views.serve),
    url(r'^(?P<path>images.*)$', views.serve),
    url(r'^(?P<path>js.*)$', views.serve)]
```

Comment: You mean you put the static files in your templates directory?

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you'd want to do this?

Comment: @Nifled do you understand what he is asking?

Comment: What I understood was that he wants to keep his paths hard-coded instead of dynamic. Hard-coded: `<link ... href="path/to/files" />`, instead of the dynamic paths with Django `<link ... href="{{ static 'file.css' }}" />`

Comment: You can do that by creating lots of nginx/apache aliases but I wouldn't recommend that.